# Invalid Identifier In SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apps

This query throws error `ORA-00904: invalid identifier`, Can anybody tell me why?

```
select papf.person_id, papf.person_number, ppnf.DISPLAY_NAME
from per_people_f papf, PER_PERSON_NAMES_F ppnf
where
papf.person_id=ppnf.person_id
and papf.person_id not in (select cs.person_id from cmp_salary cs where cs.person_id is not null and cs.ASSIGNMENT_ID is null )
and papf.person_id not in (select cse.person_id from cmp_salary_export cs where cse.person_id is not null and cse.ASSIGNMENT_ID is null )
and ppnf.name_type='US'
order by papf.person_id
```

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** error message. Do not post additional information in comments.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: The syntax is valid. Seems like you have misspelled a column or table name. Remove some stuff and try again.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. In the second sub-query you have aliased all the column references `cse.` but you have aliased the table `cs`.

```
(select cse.person_id
 from cmp_salary_export cs 
 where cse.person_id is not null 
 and cse.ASSIGNMENT_ID is null )
```

Laying out your code with proper indentations is not just pedantry: making it easier to read makes it easier to debug.